# Excel Assigning functions to text

Tags: excel, list, function

I am wondering how to do this:

For every F in a list, it means to add 1 to the input number
For every Q in a list, it means to find the negative reciprocal from the last output.

For example:

```
Number = 2
```

List:

```
Q
F
F
F
Q
```

output = -2/7  ->   -1/2 , 1 + 1/2 , 2 + 1/2 , 3 + 1/2 , -2/7

The formula will need to read from different line inputs and then go through the processes of F and Q until it reaches a final output.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use the `IF` condition. `IF(A1='F',B1+1...` like that